# GKPlayer - Store custom data

Tags: ios, game-center

Is there a way to store custom data to a GKPlayer? If no, what is the best approach to store some custom data for a GKPlayer?

I want to store GKPlayer coins earned. I cannot use leaderboard because, we cannot deduct coins from already earned coins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such way to store custom data, you can only use leaderboards and achievements - decrease of the stored amount is impossible (except resetting all achievements). If you are using Core Data to store your custom data locally then I don't recommend using iCloud to keep data globally (from your question I deduced that this is your goal, and iCloud with Core Data is bad UX solution due to time consuming first load, unexpected bugs and bad conflict resolution) - use simplier data model with iCloud or find some other server way to store coins - that would suppress possible cheats, look for some "game center like" services on the internet - I won't recommend one since I didn't use anything in practice.

**EDIT**: from recently update of Game Center capabilities there is new type of leaderboards (i checked on that just today), which allow you to store **most recent score** instead of highest one. Despite the improved cheating security on iOS 7, you have to keep your data secured on the device.